# Query Help - Where Clause

Tags: php, sql

I then have the following query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conndb1, $conndb1);
$query_rsName = sprintf("
SELECT DISTINCT 
table1.search_id, table1.search1, table1.search2, table1.search3, table1.search4, table1.search5, table1.search6, table1.search7, table1.search8, table1.search9, table1.search10, table1.search11, table1.search12, table1.search13, table1.search14, table1.search15, table1.search16, table2.search_id 

FROM table1, table2 
WHERE
 table2.criteria1 = %s OR
 table2.criteria2 = %s OR
 table2.criteria3 = %s OR
 table2.criteria4 = %s OR
 table2.criteria5 = %s OR
 table2.criteria6 = %s OR
 table2.criteria7 = %s OR
 FIND_IN_SET(%s, table2.criteria8) OR 
 table2.criteria9 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria10 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria11 = %s AND 
 table1.search_id = table2.search_id 
ORDER BY
 table1.search2 DESC", 
 GetSQLValueString($search1_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search2_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search3_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search4_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search5_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search6_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search7_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search8_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search9_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search10_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search11_rsName, "text"));
```

However, when the query is ran, it pulls all records and does each record ten times – not just the ones based on the search criteria. Now, if I change the OR to AND and select all 11, it works as it should.  Thus, it has something to do with OR operand. However, I cannot figure out what is wrong. What operand can I use besides OR that will allow this to work – to allow the searcher to select 1, 2, 3 or more criteria?

Comment: Please format you code / query. And please fox your title (make it descriptive).

Comment: you've got a Cartesian join there if you are seeing the same records returned by X the number of rows in the joining table...

Answer (score 0):

That's one hell of a query and I guess it runs for ages. Nevertheless, here is corrected one:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conndb1, $conndb1);
$query_rsName = sprintf("
SELECT DISTINCT 
table1.search_id, table1.search1, table1.search2, table1.search3, table1.search4, table1.search5, table1.search6, table1.search7, table1.search8, table1.search9, table1.search10, table1.search11, table1.search12, table1.search13, table1.search14, table1.search15, table1.search16, table2.search_id 

FROM table1, table2 
WHERE (
 table2.criteria1 = %s OR
 table2.criteria2 = %s OR
 table2.criteria3 = %s OR
 table2.criteria4 = %s OR
 table2.criteria5 = %s OR
 table2.criteria6 = %s OR
 table2.criteria7 = %s OR
 FIND_IN_SET(%s, table2.criteria8) OR 
 table2.criteria9 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria10 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria11 = %s) AND 
 table1.search_id = table2.search_id 
ORDER BY
 table1.search2 DESC", 
 GetSQLValueString($search1_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search2_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search3_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search4_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search5_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search6_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search7_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search8_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search9_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search10_rsName, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($search11_rsName, "text"));
```

Note parentheses around `OR` part of `WHERE` clause .

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I know this is an older way to code - but it is what I know and understand. I tried many things with the parentheses but not as you suggest - this worked great!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
table1.search_id, table1.search1, table1.search2, table1.search3, table1.search4, table1.search5, table1.search6, table1.search7, table1.search8, table1.search9, table1.search10, table1.search11, table1.search12, table1.search13, table1.search14, table1.search15, table1.search16, table2.search_id 

FROM table1 
join table2 on table1.search_id = table2.search_id 
WHERE
 table2.criteria1 = %s OR
 table2.criteria2 = %s OR
 table2.criteria3 = %s OR
 table2.criteria4 = %s OR
 table2.criteria5 = %s OR
 table2.criteria6 = %s OR
 table2.criteria7 = %s OR
 FIND_IN_SET(%s, table2.criteria8) OR 
 table2.criteria9 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria10 = %s OR 
 table2.criteria11 = %s 
ORDER BY
 table1.search2 DESC"
```

Comment: I don't yet understand JOIN statements but have been trying to learn as I keep running across them as I researched my issue. Thanks for your answer I will keep it in mind.

Comment: i suggest u should first do a bit of reading on joins. it is not an advanced topic in SQL. in fact it is an essential. the important thing is never to postpone the important stuff. u can google them out and understand what a basic join is. anyways having said that table1.search_id = table2.search_id is a join though. i have just moved it up to make sure that the OR and AND dont interfere with that criteria.. u r doing a join in reality urself !! but it is better to read it up..